# Vectorise a "triangular" loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

In Matlab I have the following for loop:

```
for i=1:n
    for j=i+1:n
        P(i) = P(i) - Q(j);
    end
end
```

I call this a "triangular" loop because of how `j` depends on `i`.

Is it possible to vectorise this into a single line statement that will run faster than the for loop?

Answer (score 3):

What are the type of P and Q? Are they vectors? If so what about:

```
P = P - [fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(Q(2:n)))) 0]
```

You can even do a reverse cumulative sum so the fliplr can go:

```
P = P - [cumsum(Q(2:n),'reverse') 0]
```